# pre calculate users interests

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

i need an approach or an algorithm to **pre-calculate an users interest** based on his **tweets**..

the user connects his account with his twitter account and after retrieving his tweets for the first time i will have to pre-calculate his tastes and interests..

as this user continues to use the my system i will have to make those predictions more accurate..

is there an algorithm or a mathematical model which will help in this requirement?

please provide - existing research links or open source code or examples which will help me to get started..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Machine-Learning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) for this task.

One possible machine learning algorithm is Bag Of Words with k-nearest neighbors:

Create a [**training set**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_set) [users which you know what their interest are], and use the [**Bag Of Words**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) [preferably with [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)] to "learn" the training set.

When a new user arrives - have the words/n-grams extracted as features - and find the **[k nearest neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm)** to determine what the interests are.

To get improvement over time - you can have some additional explicit feedback - users can click on agreement/disagreement for what the algorithm said. You can later use this information to extend the size of your training set - which will probably result in more accurate decisions.

This is a standrad algorithm for learning "features" between sets of sentences/words, so you should at least use it as a guideline.

There is also an open source project that might help you: [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/).

Comment: +1 can u suggest me some library's in python i am aware of nltk